# DataTables new data doesn't work

Tags: datatables

I have a table, in my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/data-tables/DT_bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body class="fixed-top">
<table id="tabela_1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Contacto</th>
<th>Dt Receção</th>
<th>Dt Validade</th>
<th>Refª Cliente</th>
<th>Num Proposta</th>
<th>Estado</th>            
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="dados_tabela">
        <tr class="">
            <td>alex</td>
            <td>Alex Nilson</td>
            <td>1234</td>
            <td class="center">power user</td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>lisa</td>
            <td>Lisa Wong</td>
            <td>434</td>
            <td class="center">new user</td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>nick12</td>
            <td>Nick Roberts</td>
            <td>232</td>
            <td class="center">power user</td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>goldweb</td>
            <td>Sergio Jackson</td>
            <td>132</td>
            <td class="center">elite user</td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>webriver</td>
            <td>Antonio Sanches</td>
            <td>462</td>
            <td class="center">new user</td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>gist124</td>
            <td>Nick Roberts</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td class="center">new user</td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>

<script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>    
<script src="../assets/breakpoints/breakpoints.js"></script>    
<script src="../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.blockui.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/data-tables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/app.js"></script>     

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {         

var oTable = $('#tabela_1').dataTable({ 
"bServerSide": true,
"bRetrieve": true,
"oSearch": {"sSearch": "Initial search"},
"sAjaxSource": "x.php?id_cliente=1",
"aoColumns": [
{ "sTitle": "Nome"},
{ "sTitle": "Data"},
{ "sTitle": "d"},
{ "sTitle": "e"},
{ "sTitle": "e"},
{ "sTitle": "3"}
],
"iDisplayLength": 10,
"bRetrieve": true,
"bScrollCollapse": true
}); 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The x.php file sends the following data:

```
(...)
$num=1;

echo '{"iTotalRecords":'.$totalRows_rs_listaconsultas.',
"iTotalDisplayRecords":"10",
"aaData":['; 


do {
if ($num>1){
echo ",";
}
echo '["',$row_rs_listaconsultas['nome'],'",
"',$row_rs_listaconsultas['datarecepcao'],'",
"',$row_rs_listaconsultas['validadeconsulta'],'",
"',$row_rs_listaconsultas['referenciaconsulta'],'",
"',$row_rs_listaconsultas['propostanumero'],'",
"',$row_rs_listaconsultas['estado'],'"]'; 
$num=$num+1;
} while ($row_rs_listaconsultas = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_listaconsultas));

echo ']}';
```

The table shows me the data from ("sAjaxSource": "php/x.php?id_cliente=1"). I can see all the data, but the sorting columns, the search box, and all the commands for reating the data are not working. It seems that the dataTable doesn't "see" the data. What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.
Mário

Comment: Do you own all domains? Same origin might be an issue here.

Comment: What do you mean about that?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Okay, I think I have that. I'm using the MAMP as a server.

Comment: Can you post the full page code?

Comment: Ok, I already edited my question. It has the full code now.

Comment: Try including the jquery and data table scripts in the head. I have experienced this before with no valid reason why.

Comment: Done, but with the same result :(((

Comment: Something else you can try is to remove temporarily the other java scripts and only have jquery and datatable scripts; there might be conflicts.

Comment: I found something about the using the ("bServerSide": true). This causes that filtering is in Server side, but if I take it out the data is not displayed... :(

Comment: Did you try my last suggestion

Comment: Yes, but no effect. Same problem. ((

Comment: I am going to replicate the same code and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need. I used the code on the datatables website:

The html should be this:

```
<html>
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" id="users" class="display">
    <thead><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#users').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "users.php"
            } );
        } );
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I used a table with just two columns an id and a name column. My data comes from the `users.php` file.

The `users.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'id', 'name');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "users";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "";
    $gaSql['server']     = "";

    /* REMOVE THIS LINE (it just includes my SQL connection user/pass) */
    //include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/datatables/mysql.php" );


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /* 
     * Local functions
     */
    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }


    /* 
     * MySQL connection
     */
    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    }

    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
    }


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
                    ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`)
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Change these variables:

1. `$aColumns = array( 'id', 'name');` //fields in your table
2. `$sIndexColumn = "id";` //indexing column
3. `$sTable = "users";` //the table name
4. Necessary connection variables:

   $gaSql['user']       = "";
   $gaSql['password']   = "";
   $gaSql['db']         = "";
   $gaSql['server']     = "";

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Now I could see some progress... I tried like you said, but I get the erros : "DataTables warning (table id = 'tabela_1'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error." I've checked the users.php output and it's a JSON ok (at least to me) any idea? My Json output:
{
sEcho: 0,
iTotalRecords: "56",
iTotalDisplayRecords: "48",
aaData: [
[
"1",
"2013-04-04",
"Email 26-03-2013",
null,
"Aguarda consulta aos fornecedores"
],
[
"1",
"Paulo Leal",
"2011-12-22",
null,
"Aguarda consulta aos fornecedores"
]
]
}

Comment: Good luck. If you need anymore help, post again

Comment: Do you think it's because of that 'null' data?

Comment: Your table should not have any content, it should look like the example I showed you.

Comment: I'm using this theme: http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic (The table in questions is in Menu > Data Tables > Editable Tables). Could you, please, try to the same with this table? I don't have enough knowledgements to check what's going wrong .. :(( Could you do this?

Comment: I can share the theme with you, in my dropbox account